# Computability and continuous real functions

Tags: real-analysis, computer-science

I have found somewhere the following statement:

> "Every computable real function has to be continuous,"

but I'm not able to prove it and the "proofs" that I found in some blog posts don't seem rigorous enough to me. Could you provide a formal proof of the statement?

**Note:** I have some knowledge of Turing machines.

Comment: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/01/what-does-topology-have-to-do-with.html

Comment: Is a step function computable?

Comment: @KyleGannon Could you point out a more academic presentation?

Comment: In _intuitionistic mathematics_, __Brouwer's Continuity Theorem__ boldly states that
all total real functions are (uniformly) continuous on the unit interval.
Somewhat more elaborate/general: any (total real) function which is defined
everywhere at an interval of real numbers is also continuous at the same
interval. With other words: For real valued functions, being defined is
very much the same as being continuous. In view of the above, is this a coincidence? I think not.
Sad remark: it's difficult to find a reference for the theorem nowadays.

Comment: @Bernard: A step function is not computable where it steps :-(

Comment: @HandeBruijn, how can that possibly be true? if we have the step function $f(x)=0 \text { if } x<0, f(x)=1 \text { if } x\leq 0$, then it is discontinuous at $0$, but I can compute it: $f(0)=1$. There I've just computed it. So the step function is computable. I just computed it. Is this a joke? I checked whether the question was posted on April 1, but no. I must either significantly misunderstand something, or the world has gone mad.

Comment: @Programmer2134: According to LEJ Brouwer, such a "function" is not a function, because _in intuitionistic mathematics_ it is "multiple valued" at $x=0$. If you take a look at an oscilloscope with the Heaviside on it, then this point of view makes more sense than you might think at first sight. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @HandeBruijn, Could you elaborate? I don't understand the oscilloscope example.

Comment: @Programmer2134: Consider instead the function:
$$
H(x) = \lim_{\sigma\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is proved on the book *[Computable Analysis: An Introduction](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=Ir6qCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=every%20computable%20real%20function%20is%20continuous&source=bl&ots=EEn_2o1yV1&sig=kKsTM3_9-eL--M8I65HHY7bvZSA&hl=es-419&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=every%20computable%20real%20function%20is%20continuous&f=false)* written by Klaus Weihrauch