# Computability, Continuity and Constructivism

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, computer-science, philosophy, constructive-mathematics

Triggered by an IMO extremely interesting question & Mathematics Stack Exchange,
asked by Dal:

- [Computability and continuous real functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088045/computability-and-continuous-real-functions)

And a link in one of the comments that could have served as an answer but it didn't.
(*Warning.* Norton Internet Security blocked an intrusion from this page;
I don't know how serious that is):

- [What does topology have to do with computability?](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/01/what-does-topology-have-to-do-with.html)

> *Theorem.*
>   **All well-defined computable functions are continuous**.
>   [ Proof. ] Consider Cauchy's definition of continuity. The function $f$
>   is continuous at $x$ if for all $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$
>   such that whenever $|y-x|<\delta$, $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. There's
>   another way of phrasing that. $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for any 
>   $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that even if the argument, $x$,
>   to $f$ has an error of $\delta$, $f(x)$ still has an accuracy of
>   $\epsilon$. So now think about exact reals defined by Cauchy sequences.
>   Suppose $f$ is a well-defined function, as above. Then to find $f(x)$
>   to within $2^m$ we just need to find the $m$-th term in the Cauchy
>   sequence $f$ returns. If $f$ is a computable function, it obviously
>   can only examine a finite number of elements of the sequence of $x$.
>   Suppose the latest element in the sequence it looks at is the $n$th one.
>   Then if $f$ is implemented correctly it's managing to compute $f(x)$ to
>   an accuracy of $2^m$ even though its input was only known to an accuracy
>   of $2^n$. In other words, $f$ is continuous. (Choose $m$ such that
>   $2^m<\epsilon$ and $\delta<2^n$.)

There is another thing, seemingly unrelated to it. But I don't believe
that things may be unrelated and yet are quite similar in mathematics.

In *intuitionistic mathematics*, **Brouwer's Continuity Theorem**
boldly states that all total real functions are (uniformly) continuous on the unit
interval. Somewhat more elaborate/general: any (total real) function which
is defined everywhere at an interval of real numbers is also continuous at
the same interval. With other words: for real valued functions, just being
defined is very much the same as being continuous. 
**All constructively well-defined functions are continuous**.
Oh well, more or less. But anyway, the similarity with the same property for computable functions is clear herewith.

*Question*. Is the abovementioned similarity just a coincidence?
Or is there a deeper reason for it? How exactly may computable
and constructive be related to each other?

*Sad remark*. It's difficult to find good references for Brouwer's Continuity Theorem at the internet nowadays. I took the freedom to make a mirror of this relevant
one available:

- [Understanding and using Brouwer's continuity principle - Wim Veldman](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/18854.pdf)

*Disclaimer*. The above is more or less what I understand of Brouwer's Continuity Theorem. For me, as a physicist by education, there doesn't seem to be an essential difference between constructive and computable. But that may be short-sighted. Hence the question.

Comment: You can see Michael Beeson, [Foundations of constructive mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=wKtKAQAAIAAJ&) (1985); **Ch.III: Some different philosophies of Constructive Mathematics**.

Comment: You can see also : Douglas Bridges, [Introducing Constructive Mathematics](http://www.masfak.ni.ac.rs/cmfp2013/Nis%20lecture%20170113.pdf).

Comment: For a physicist, see Marian Pour-El & Ian Richards, [Computability in Analysis and Physics](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422917) (1989).

Comment: See also in Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&pg=PA1) (1988) : **Ch.1 : Introduction** for a good overview of the different approach to constructivism.

Comment: Also Klaus Weihrauch, [A Simple Introduction to Computable Analysis](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/resources/pdf/ica.pdf) (1995).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Many more references than I hoped for. Thank you!