# Approaching to a number and limit

Tags: limits

Consider $f(x)$ function . We want to calculate $\lim_{x \to 3}f(x)$. So for left limit , we approach to $3$ and then compute $f(2.9) , f(2.99) , f(2.999)$ and so on . Now there is a weird thing . It is obvious that $2.9999.... = 3$ and also when we are talking about limit , point isn't important . In this case we don't take care about $f(3)$ but when we approach to $3$ infinitely , we get $3$ as $2.9999.... = 3$ ! . I'm very confused about these two concepts .

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209417/limit-and-0-999-dots-1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you but it is a different question .

Comment: @DietrichBurde Linking to a confused question that might or might not be relevant, and which has no clarifying comments or answers doesn't help, I think.

Comment: @Arthur It is the same author for this question, and possibly with the same problem, with $2.9999....=3$. I find it related.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes , I wrote it but it was wrong question and the right question is this .

Comment: But what is the question ?

Comment: @A---B The question that I wrote here is my problem .

Comment: @S.H.W You say you are confused about two concepts but I fail to understand what two concepts. Can you please tell me ? You may have wrote a question in the thread but it is not obvious since you have not used question mark to separate it.

Comment: @A---B The first concept is limit and second is $2.99999.... = 3$. If you read again the question I think it will be clear.

Comment: @S.H.W You don't understand what a limit is ? What is your problem with $2.999... = 3$ ? you said you know it is true in the question.

Comment: As I understand this it's not really about why $2.999\ldots=3$. There are plenty of $0.999\ldots=1$ questions on this site already with great answers anyways. I think this is about how the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from below along $2,2.9,2.99,\ldots$ can be different from the function value at $2.999\ldots=3$. Is that what your question is about, or is it something else?

Comment: @Arthur Yes , that is .

Comment: Related Mathematics SE questions : 
[Is any real-valued function in physics somehow continuous?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830199/is-any-real-valued-function-in-physics-somehow-continuous) ,
[Computability, Continuity and Constructivism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166629/computability-continuity-and-constructivism) . Bottom line: it's an intelligent question and the OP is not the only one who is struggling with these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in order to find that some real $l$ is the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to3^-}f(x)
$$
you *don't* compute $f(2.9)$, $f(2.99)$ and so on. And neither you compute $f(2.(9))$ (periodic $9$), because *no* assumption is made that $f$ is defined at $3$, nor the possible value of $f$ at $3$ is relevant for the existence of the limit.

Saying that
$$
\lim_{x\to3^-}f(x)=l
$$
means

> for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $3-\delta<x<3$, it holds $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

You *can* compute $f(2.9...9)$, if you wish; it *may* give you an idea of what $l$ could be, but in general it won't.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still  confused . My problem is this : What's the difference between closing to a number infinitely and reaching it ?

Comment: @S.H.W There is *no* “closing to a number” in the definition I gave. Some teachers still like to use that language, notwithstanding that precise and rigorous definitions have been developed about 200 years ago.

Comment: Please take a look at it : https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-formal.html

Comment: I think as you can see in "Mathisfun" page , the epsilon-delta definition is same as closing to a number .

Comment: @S.H.W I recommend you *not* to learn math from that site.

Comment: My calculus also said that. I think it is right.

Comment: Reviewing this question after 6 years, I think in addition to the provided answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697814/function-converges-iff-when-every-sequence-converges-the-sequence-of-function-va) theorem helps to understand the convergence of a function at a point. So the convergence of $f(2.9),f(2,99),\dots$ isn't sufficient. For **every** sequence $a_n \to 3$ the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ should converge to $L$.

Comment: @S.H.W When I was a student of mathematics, our fellow engineering students all had powerful (for the time) calculators and the job of their instructors was inventing functions that would give hints to the actual limits only when going beyond the accuracy of those calculators. So, inputting $10^{-12}$ might have shown something near $3$, but the actual limit might have been $20$. And your remark is correct: you would need to check *all* sequences, not just one. This is why presenting “approaching” the way that site does is, to say the least, misleading.

Comment: Yes, now (although a little bit late): I understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: @S.H.W Don't worry! It took a couple of centuries to get calculus well founded!

Comment: Yes indeed :-).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a limit $\mathit{x}\rightarrow \mathit{n}$ is that you approach to $\mathit{n}$ as close as possible, but you actually never reach it.

Just forget that you are "computing" $f$ at every point because it is a missunderstanding. Imagine that you are moving along the graph of the function $f$, then when taking a limit you are getting as close as possible to a specific point without ever touching it, as the function does not need to be $defined$ at that point, or the image might be different than the limit itself.

Imagine the following case:

$$f(x) = \left \lbrace {x^2, x \not= 0 \atop
1 , x = 0}\right. $$

If you take $lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x) = 0$ for both right and left limits, but the actual image is $f(0)=1$.

When one has the equallity between right limit, left limit and image at a certain point in a function, we then say that the function is $continuous$, but any function that is not continuous still has limits.

I hope I clarified that to you.

edit: keep in mind that when talking about real numbers, between any two numbers there is an infinity of more numbers, it doesn't matter how close you try to imagine them to be, and that is the idea exploited by the limit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still  confused . My problem is this : What's the difference between closing to a number infinitely and reaching it ?

Comment: @S.H.W Ayeron gives a good example of the difference. As long as $x$ is not $0$ - _no matter how close to $0$ it is_ then $f(x)=x^2$. But when $x=0$ ("reaching it" in your terms) $f(x)=1$. BTW, in standard real analysis $\epsilon, \delta$ are real numbers. Being real numbers they are not infinite, infinitesimals, or infinitely close to other real numbers. In other words there is a distinction between "arbitrarily close" and "infinitely close" or similar statements. There is a branch of math called "non-standard real analysis" that deals with infinitesimals. Wikipedia has an article on it.

Comment: @user2460798 Consider this definition : $\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; \delta > 0: |x- 3| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ . Can we choose $2.999...$ for $x$ ?

Comment: @user2460798 You said , "there is a distinction between "arbitrarily close" and "infinitely close" or similar statements." . In real analysis for finding the limit we are dealing with infinitely close or arbitrarily close to a number ?

Comment: Arbitrarily close.

Comment: @S.H.W No you can't choose $2.999...$ because $\delta$ must be $>0$.

Comment: @user2460798 Therefore if we compute finite numbers  like ($f(2.9) , f(2.99) , .....)$ , how we can guarantee that its pattern will not change ?

Comment: You can't. You could have a term like $sin(1/(x-3))$ which changes sign more frequently the closer $x$ is to $3$. As has been said elsewhere in this thread, computing values using specific values of $x$ isn't how the delta/epsilon method works.